# Is it possible to write a windows driver to restrict access to file based on executable name or attributes?

Tags: 64-bit, driver, windows-10-desktop

If yes, what example of Microsoft fits in best as skeleton of my driver? I mean windows ddk driver samples. I downloaded EWDK_rs5_release_17763_180914-1434.iso, but no setup, why?
I can only find LaunchBuildEnv.cmd  . I have VS 2017 installed on my system.

Thanks!

Comment: EWDK is command-line based and is portable, and thus it isn't installed like the normal one nor come with a VS plugin. As for what you want to do from kernel-mode, look into writing a Filesystem Mini-Filter driver - you can restrict access for different I/O Request Packets (IRPs) such as IRP_MJ_CREATE from within your callback routine/s.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltregisterfilter https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/ns-fltkernel-_flt_registration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/ns-fltkernel-_flt_operation_registration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/nc-fltkernel-pflt_pre_operation_callback https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/nc-fltkernel-pflt_post_operation_callback

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/content/fltkernel/nf-fltkernel-fltstartfiltering

Comment: You can find the official MS samples for this here: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-driver-samples/tree/master/filesys/miniFilter/

Comment: thanks, can I use irq_mj_create for file delete attempt, too? or it uses another irq?